# binding style attributes inside each-loop

Tags: ember.js

I have this code:

```
    {{#each hotspots as |hotspot|}}
      {{#unless (eq hotspot.x_axis "")}}
        {{#if (eq categoryId hotspot.category)}}
          {{#draggable-item content=hotspot.id dragEnter=(action "setIsDragged" "isDragged") dragEnd=(action "setIsDragged" false)}}
            <div {{action 'showMarkerModal' hotspot.id}} class="normal-markers {{isDragged}}" style="position:absolute;top:{{{hotspot.y_axis}}}px;left:{{{hotspot.x_axis}}}px;"><i class="fa fa-map-marker {{isDragged}}"></i></div>
          {{/draggable-item}}
          <span style="position:absolute;top:{{{hotspot.y_axis}}}px;left:{{{hotspot.x_axis}}}px;">
          </span>
        {{/if}}
      {{/unless}}
    {{/each}}
```

Which gives me the following warning:

> WARNING: Binding style attributes may introduce cross-site scripting
>   vulnerabilities; please ensure that values being bound are properly
>   escaped. For more information, including how to disable this warning,
>   see
>   http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_binding-style-attributes.

I know why the warning is being thrown, but I can't figure out how to bind the inline attributes as the x_axis and y_axis are coming from inside the handlebars file itself. So I cant do a computed property to solve this.

Has anyone come across of this before and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the iteration body in a component, and create the computed properties in the component:

```
{{#each hotspots as |hotspot|}}
  {{#unless (eq hotspot.x_axis "")}}
    {{#if (eq categoryId hotspot.category)}}
      {{my-draggable-item content=hotspot.id
          dragEnter=(action "setIsDragged" "isDragged")
          dragEnd=(action "setIsDragged" false)
          isDragged=isDragged
          showMarkerModal="showMarkerModal"}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/unless}}
{{/each}}


// my-draggable-item.hbs
{{#draggable-item content=content dragEnter=dragEnter dragEnd=dragEnd}}
  <div {{action 'showMarkerModal' hotspot.id}} class="normal-markers {{isDragged}}" style={{computedStyle}}><i class="fa fa-map-marker {{isDragged}}"></i></div>
{{/draggable-item}}
<span style={{computedStyle}}></span>


// my-draggable-item.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  computedStyle: Ember.computed('hotspot.{x_axis,y_axis}', function() {
    let xAxis = this.get('hotspot.x_axis');
    let yAxis = this.get('hotspot.y_axis');

    return Ember.String.htmlSafe(`position:absolute;top:${yAxis}px;left:${xAxis}px;`);
  }),

  actions: {
    showMarkerModal(id) {
      this.sendAction('showMarkerModal', id);
    }
  }
}};
```

`"hotspot.{x_axis,y_axis}"` is called "brace expansion" and is the same as `"hotspot.x_axis, hotspot.y_axis"`.
Backticks and `${}` are interpolated [ES2015 template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

I had to pass in the properties and actions, I might have missed something.
I hope it at least gives you an idea of the solution.

Comment: Not the exact solution, but managed to do it with some tweaks, u definitely pointed me in the right direction! Thank you.